# I want to read a particular row from excel in java

Tags: java

I want to read a particular row from excel. I already have the code to read from excel, but it's for all rows. I just want to read a particular row on basis of some condition.

```
    File fis=new File("D:\\Sachin\\SOL.xls");

     Workbook work=Workbook.getWorkbook(fis);


     Sheet s=work.getSheet(0);
     int rows=s.getRows();

     int column=s.getColumns();


     for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
     {
         for(int j=0;j<column;j++)
         {
             Cell cell=s.getCell(j, i);
             System.out.println(cell.getContents());
         }
         System.out.println("");
     }

}
```

Comment: have you tried sheet.getRow(rowIndex) ?
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getRow(int)

Answer (score 2):

Replacing this line:

```
     Workbook work=Workbook.getWorkbook(fis);
```

With:

```
     HSSFWorkbook work = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

And try to use something like this:

```
     HSSFWorkbook work = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
     HSSFSheet hssfSheet = work.getSheetAt(0);
     for (int rn=startRowNo; rn<=endRowNo; rn++) 
        {
      HSSFRow row = hssfSheet.getRow(rn);
      // processing here your row
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use HSSFWorkBook here and then HSSFRow to get the row with row number.

```
HSSFRow row = hssfSheet.getRow(rn);
```